# FTP Connection string using expression in SSIS

Tags: sql-server-2005, ssis, ftp, expression

In my SSIS 2005 package, I need to give the FTP Connectionstring via an expression as I need to keep it configurable for the user from the dtsConfig file.

At the moment I tried giving the following expression:

Connectionstring = @[User::FTPServer] + "." + @[User::FTPUser] + "." + @[User::FTPPass]

For this unique syntax, I took pointers from the discussion at http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/3713e9a5-343a-4c5b-ac5d-1508cd5ab8be

My FTPServer variable also has port info in the format MYSERVERNAME:21.

But I am getting the error "530 User anonymous unknown"

Any idea how I can fix this error?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think your variables should have two `::` not one.

`@[User::FTPServer] + "." + @[User::FTPUser] + "." + @[User::FTPPass]`

**EDIT:**

You may be having some trouble due to the [password being cleared](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/sqlintegrationservices/thread/80e0b079-a4b7-4c03-b646-563541cbc997/)

What I would do is set these details beforehand via a Script Task. Run the script and then run the FTP Task - I think that should that work.

```
Public Class ScriptMain

Public Sub Main()

Dim FTPConnectionManager As ConnectionManager

'Set variable to an existing connection manager
' Replace "FTP Server" with the name of your existing FTP Connection Manager
FTPConnectionManager = Dts.Connections("FTP Server")


FTPConnectionManager.Properties("ServerName").SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, Dts.Variables("FTPServer").Value)

FTPConnectionManager.Properties("ServerPort").SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, Dts.Variables("FTPPort").Value)

FTPConnectionManager.Properties("ServerUserName").SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, Dts.Variables("FTPUserName").Value)

FTPConnectionManager.Properties("ServerPassword").SetValue(FTPConnectionManager, Dts.Variables("FTPPassword").Value)


Dts.TaskResult = Dts.Results.Success

End Sub

End Class
```

Comment: sorry, that was a typo in my question.. fixing my question