# What is the expression syntax for setting a FTPConnection password with BIML?

Tags: ssis, biml

I am generating SSIS packages with BIML and I am setting up my FTPConnection like this:

```
<FtpConnection Name="FTP" ServerName="srv003809" Password="" ServerPort="21" UsePassiveMode="true" >
    <Expressions>
        <Expression PropertyName="ServerName">@[User::mst_strFTP_Server]</Expression>
        <Expression PropertyName="ServerPort">@[User::mst_strFTP_Port]</Expression>
        <Expression PropertyName="ServerUserName">@[User::mst_strFTP_Username]</Expression>     
        <Expression PropertyName="ServerPassword">@[User::mst_strFTP_Password]</Expression> 
    </Expressions>
</FtpConnection>
```

When I generate the package I get this error:

```
Could not resolve reference to 'ServerPassword' of type 'PropertyExpression'. 'PropertyName="ServerPassword"' is invalid.
Provide valid scoped name
```

I have tried changing `ServerPassword` to `Password` without success. I can't find much on the BIML forums in connection with FTP connections.

How do I set the FTP connection password using an expression in BIML?

I am using Visual Studio 2010 and BIDSHelper 2012 (1.7.0.0)

Comment: Couple of thoughts... I think you'll have to change the 'Connection' property, not the individual components.  Other thought is, since it's BIML, can you offload those variables into BIML control blocks as C# vars, and then access it in a BIML expression block?  And finally, can you utilize [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/3888262/974077) to create a Script Task?

Comment: Thanks @sorrell I finally got around to trying your suggestions. Setting the "connection" or "ConnectionString" doesn't seem to work, but using a script task does the job - seems a bit heavy handed, but it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of using the **PropertyName**, try using **ExternalProperty**. I was having a similar problem using variables and expressions using an Odbc connection, and changing it to ***ExternalProperty="Password" and ExternalProperty="UserName"*** worked for me.

I am still looking for the difference between Property and ExternalProperty, and will post once I am able to find something.

Comment: [Difference between the `PropertyName` and `ExternalProperty`](https://www.varigence.com/Documentation/Language/Element/AstPropertyExpressionNode)

Comment: Can confirm if you import a package with a connection set to an expression on the `Password` property it creates it as `<Expression ExternalProperty="Password">@[User::FtpPassword]</Expression>`. At least using [BimlOnline](http://bimlonline.com/app)

Comment: Thanks, that works. For the FTP connector you need to use:
`<Expression ExternalProperty="ServerPassword">@[User::strFTP_Password]</Expression>`